# How to call python script in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a `metrics.py` which calculates a graph.

I can call it in the terminal command line (`python ./metrics.py -i [input] [output]`).

I want to write a function in Spark. It calls the `metrics.py` script to run on the provide file path and collects the values that `metrics.py` prints out.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run metrics.py, you essentially ship it to all the executor nodes that run your Spark Job.

To do this, you either pass it via SparkContext -

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf, pyFiles=['path_to_metrics.py'])
```

or pass it later using the Spark Context's addPyFile method -

```
sc.addPyFile('path_to_metrics.py')
```

In either case, after that, do not forget to import metrics.py and then just call needed function that gives needed output.

```
import metrics
metrics.relevant_function()
```

Also make sure you have all the python libraries that are imported inside metrics.py installed on all executor nodes. Else, take care of them using the --py-files and --jars handles while spark-submitting your job.